# memory address gets cut off after 8 digits

Tags: c++

memory address gets cuts off after 8 digits help

```
DWORD* memoryAddress = (DWORD*)0x155221000;
```

turns from 0x155221000 into 0x55221000 after conversion.

Comment: How do you know what's stored in your pointer value?

Comment: `DWORD` is 4 bytes so it should be able to store... a maximum of `0xFFFFFFFF`. Exactly what you're seeing.

Comment: you are supposed to store memory addresses as pointers and i forgot it was in hex and so it was a 64 bit hex memadress i was trying to access using so small things like DWORD  when i needed to use DWORD64* for the 64 bit programs memory addresses thanks all answers.

Comment: Is this on Windows?  If so, the datatype you are looking for is `DWORD_PTR`, or maybe `uintptr_t`.

Answer (score 1):

On a 32bits system, an address is 4 bytes long. So `DWORD* memoryAddress = (DWORD*)0x155221000;` would be truncated by definition (also bad to use C-style casts). The compiler should give you a truncation warning by the way.

`1428295680` is the base-10 representation of the same value (addresses are usually represented in hexadecimal, still the same value).

As the comments from different people said, `DWORD` is 4 bytes (just a coincidence that addresses are also 4 bytes), it would also truncate your number for the same reason.